# How can I display to the user when Pusher is going to reconnect?

Tags: javascript, pusher

How can I display a message to the user, who is offline that says:

```
Reconnecting in X seconds
```

I've seen the [connecting_in](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/blob/7d4160038b5836163af2bdc23aabce6219a9c242/src/core/connection/connection_manager.ts#L189) event, but its not being fired when I disconnect my computer from the internet.

So, how can I display the retry interval to the user?